# Star Rating buttons not rendering as expected using React.JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So my my star buttons are showing on my U.I. as expected but there not rendering. I can change the output of them by changing the integer value of my CurrentRating in my state function whether I change it to 1, 2, 3, ect. But that's it.

After clicking on any button, the star on that button and the stars before it are supposed to turn red.

What am I missing?

Here's my code:

card.js ///

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";


 import { Stars } from "./stars";

 export class Card extends Component {
 // Initiatte clicks at 0
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {


   CurrentRating: 0,
 };
}

// Rate your instructor
handleRating = (value) => {
  console.log("Rating declared");
this.setState({ CurrentRating: value });
};
///

render() {
  // Create a variable for Star rating
  const Rating = this.state.CurrentRating;

  return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div className="container">
      

      <div className="stars">
        <p>Your rating is {Rating}</p>
        <Stars rating={Rating} onClicked={this.handleRating} />
      </div>
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
  );
 }
}

export default Card;
```

stars.CSS ///

```
.active {
color: red;
}
```

stars.js ///

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./stars.css";


export class Stars extends Component {
///
render() {
// Sample props
  const Rating = this.props.rating;
  console.log("[Stars] Render, Rating=" + Rating);

  /// Render or Genrate markup.
  return (
  <div>
    {Rating >= 1 && (
      <button
        className="active"
        onClick={this.onClicked}
        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
      >
        ★
      </button>
    )}

    {Rating < 1 && (
      <button onClick={this.onClicked} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
        ★
      </button>
    )}

    {Rating >= 2 && (
      <button
        className="active"
        onClick={this.onClicked}
        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
      >
        ★
      </button>
    )}

    {Rating < 2 && (
      <button onClick={this.onClicked} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
        ★
      </button>
    )}

    {Rating >= 3 && (
      <button
        className="active"
        onClick={this.onClicked}
        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
      >
        ★
      </button>
    )}

    {Rating < 3 && (
      <button onClick={this.onClicked} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
        ★
      </button>
    )}

    {Rating >= 4 && (
      <button
        className="active"
        onClick={this.onClicked}
        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
      >
        ★
      </button>
    )}

    {Rating < 4 && (
      <button onClick={this.onClicked} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
        ★
      </button>
    )}

    {Rating >= 5 && (
      <button
        className="active"
        onClick={this.onClicked}
        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
      >
        ★
      </button>
    )}

    {Rating < 5 && (
      <button onClick={this.onClicked} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
        ★
      </button>
    )}
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

App.js ///

```
 import './App.css';

 import { Card } from './card';

 function App() {
   return (
     <div className="App">
     <header className="App-header">
   
      <Card />
   
    </header>
  </div>
  );
 }

 export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the function you're calling when the button is clicked

```
 <button onClick={this.onClicked}
```

Firstly, this should be `this.props.onClicked` as the function is passed in as a prop (rather than being on the Stars class itself).

Secondly, you need to pass the actual value of the rating in the function. i.e.

```
 <button onClick={() => this.props.onClicked(1)}
```

If I make the change above on the first button and click it, it turns red

Comment: It looks great! Thanks for your help!

Comment: But for my Like Increment Button all I need to use is onClick={this.props.onLike}, without using () =>. Why do I have to use () => for the Star Buttons but no my Like Increment Button?

Comment: Without seeing your like increment button, my assumption is that it takes no arguments when you call the function.

Essentially when you have something like onClick={this.props.onLike} React is calling your function as this.props.onLike(event) where event contains a bunch of information about the event itself (target element, etc)

Comment: However in the case of your onClicked function, you don't want the event, you want to pass in the number value of the star (this could be inferred via the event, but I won't go into that now).
Effectively this change to onClick is doing onClick={(event) => this.props.onClicked(1)} but we don't use the event, so discard it.

Comment: Yeah it is true for my Like Increment Button I am using "target" in the event. Overall thanks for info, I 'll keep it mind for next time.